# mysql timestamp now() is not working with nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am trying to insert a row into mysql table using nodejs. I am trying to update a column creation_date(timestamp) by sending its value as now() in nodejs, but it is giving an error saying that "now" is not defined. When I am executing the same sql query in mysql directly, it is working. I do not know where the problem is. Can somebody please help me here...
This is the nodejs code where I am inserting values into the table in mysql..

```
var sql = `INSERT INTO sales
    (
        user_id, name, tagline, start_date, 
        start_time, end_date, reg_start, 
        reg_end, descr, creation_date
    ) VALUES (
        ?, ?, ?, ?,
        ?, ?, ?,
        ?, ?, ?
    )`

pool.query(sql, [
    id, req.body.sale_name, req.body.tag, req.body.start,
    req.body.stime, req.body.end, req.body.reg_start,
    req.body.start, req.body.descr, now()
], function (err, result) { //further code})
```

The error which I am getting is : ReferenceError: now is not defined

Comment: few questions :: is your client and db server running in same timezone? if not which datetime you want to store in db? if you want to store the db time you can ignore this feild in query use NOW() as default value in sql.

Comment: You have to use 'NOW()' . A silly mistake i guess.

Comment: Yes it is working in the same timezone

Comment: you are using node js so use  new Date()  instead now().now() works when you insert data using mysql

Comment: Have you tried above?

Comment: Yes and it worked!! Thank u @ChandrakantThakkar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get today's date by using general JavaScript object.

```
var datetime = new Date();
```

So, I guess you should write smth like this:

```
pool.query(sql, [
    id, req.body.sale_name, req.body.tag, req.body.start,
    req.body.stime, req.body.end, req.body.reg_start,
    req.body.start, req.body.descr, new Date()
], function (err, result) { //further code})
```

Comment: Date() returns the server's time. You should use Date.now(), it returns the UTC time https://github.com/drudge/mongoose-timestamp/issues/23#issue-51846618

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting this error because now() works on MYSQL where running now() in javascript looking for function which doesn't exist in your script.

Correct way of loading date in Javascript is "Date.now();"

Reference: [JavaScript now() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_now.asp)

Answer (score 1):

**TIMESTAMP** and **DATETIME** columns can be automatically initialized and updated to the current date and time (that is, the current timestamp) in **MySQL**.

So, here you can set current timestamp without passing it from the client side. Whenever a row is inserted in the MySQL database then the current timestamp will automatically set to the **TIMESTAMP**/ **DATETIME** column.

CREATE TABLE Statement:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  // rest of the statements
  'creation_timestamp' TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  'creation_datetime' DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
);
```

Now, whenever a row is inserted into the database then the *creation_timestamp*/*creation_datetime* column will be automatically set to the current timestamp.

**Note:**

1. Here, you don't need to pass any date or timestamp in the insert statement from the client side.
2. You can learn more about it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have to give now() as a String like that:

```
  pool.query(sql, [
    id, req.body.sale_name, req.body.tag, req.body.start,
    req.body.stime, req.body.end, req.body.reg_start,
    req.body.start, req.body.descr, 'now()'
  ], function (err, result) { //further code})
```

Comment: The row got inserted into the table but the value was 00-00-0000 00:00:00 got saved in the table.

Comment: @MeghaVerma that's because it's not using `NOW()` it's using `'NOW()'`. I'm surprised it converted the string into a date and didn't just error out.`